# Awk: set RS to include newline and 1st (only) field of next row // logfile "splits" based on custom RS and print matching pattern therein

Tags: awk, text-processing, unix-text-processing

The short version of the question: **To which value to set RS in `awk` to split records based on each line whose n-th field is empty ?** (if line would be completely empty ,i.e. no Timestamp field in my examples, then setting `RS="\n\n ..."` would do.

The long version:
This is how my log file looks like (notice the intertwined sections related to `**amd64**` resp. `**arm64**`) :

```
...
2023-12-29T16:05:20.3032116Z 
2023-12-29T16:05:20.3040485Z #10 [linux/arm64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4084773Z #10 DONE 0.8s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085104Z 
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085552Z #11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5499792Z #11 DONE 0.1s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5505699Z 
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5509862Z #12 [linux/amd64 builder 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5512029Z #12 0.138 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6982466Z #12 ...
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6983744Z
2023-12-29T16:05:21.2474882Z #16 [linux/arm64 runner 2/7] RUN addgroup -S -g 1001 nodejs
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3971789Z #16 ...
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3972318Z 
...
```

.... as can be seen, each section ends with an line which doesn't contain anything *except* a Timestamp

The goal is to print separately the sections (lines) for each of  **amd64** and for **arm64**, e.g. (for amd64):

```
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085104Z      <-- ideally be present in output
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085552Z #11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5499792Z #11 DONE 0.1s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5505699Z       <-- ideally be present in output
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5509862Z #12 [linux/amd64 builder 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5512029Z #12 0.138 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
```

The ideal *solution* would:

- not mandatory to make use of `awk`, except when solutions in `sed` & co. are really overkill and more 'script-like'
- be relatively easy to remember /  and intuitively to replicate for repeated similar use-cases
- not be too specific, i.e. work for other first (or *n-th*) field (not necessary for Timestamp-like formatted field)
- not use any other extra Tools besides the main one (e.g. `awk` )

The followig solution only works (partially) but only **if** the log **didn't** have any fields in the empty lines (e.g. no Timestamp field):
`awk -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '/amd64 builder/ 1'  logfile`.
**however**, and as an extra question:  why (and how to correct it) does this solution print *twice,* in the *first* section of the output, the keyword searched for, i.e. amd64 in my case? Other (subsequent) sections only have the keyword *once* (as expected) ?

Thanks

LE: just realized that, without preserving the line with just the Timestamp in it, the output is hard to read .. so if you guys @Ed Morton and @markp-fuso could adjust a little bit your answers to preserve that line ? Thank you !

Comment: keep the timestamp-only line? or print a (true) blank line between each block of output?

Comment: whichever  solution is more straightforward / shorter; ideally would be preserving the Timestamp line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v tgt='amd64' 'NF<2{f=""; next} !f{f=($3 ~ ("/"tgt"$"))} f' file
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085552Z #11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5499792Z #11 DONE 0.1s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5509862Z #12 [linux/amd64 builder 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5512029Z #12 0.138 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6982466Z #12 ...
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='arm64' 'NF<2{f=""; next} !f{f=($3 ~ ("/"tgt"$"))} f' file
2023-12-29T16:05:20.3040485Z #10 [linux/arm64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4084773Z #10 DONE 0.8s
2023-12-29T16:05:21.2474882Z #16 [linux/arm64 runner 2/7] RUN addgroup -S -g 1001 nodejs
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3971789Z #16 ...
```

- `NF<2{f=""; next}` clears the flag `f` when there's only a timestamp
  on the line.
- `!f{f=($3 ~ ("/"tgt"$"))}` sets `f` to `1` (if `tgt` is present) or `0` (otherwise) when each line that looks like `#11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8]` is read.
- `f` causes the current line to be printed when `f` is `1`.

I don't know why you thought setting `RS` to `\n\n` would work for you, it fails because doing so is unrelated to your problem.

Given your comments, it sounds like this is what you're looking for (using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `\S/\s`):

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\\S+\\s*\n' -v ORS= '/amd64/{print $0 RT}' file
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085552Z #11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5499792Z #11 DONE 0.1s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5505699Z
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5509862Z #12 [linux/amd64 builder 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5512029Z #12 0.138 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6982466Z #12 ...
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6983744Z
```

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\\S+\\s*\n' -v ORS= '/arm64/{print $0 RT}' file
2023-12-29T16:05:20.3032116Z
2023-12-29T16:05:20.3040485Z #10 [linux/arm64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4084773Z #10 DONE 0.8s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085104Z
2023-12-29T16:05:21.2474882Z #16 [linux/arm64 runner 2/7] RUN addgroup -S -g 1001 nodejs
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3971789Z #16 ...
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3972318Z
```

Comment: That _was_ fast :) 
1. can you please explain a little bit, esp. the part  " !f{f=($3 ~ ("/"tgt"$"))} f' " , i.e. when current line processed is not  the Timestamp-only line ?
2. would appreciate if you could answer  the question(s) i had  edited in my initial question please, T .y !

Comment: (1) any possibility to use a regexp (or something somewhat resembling RS="\n$1" ) to match 'newline and $1 of following line' as RS? (2) just noticed your question about setting RS to \n\n: That would've worked only when no Timestamp would be present, i.e. the line would've been completely empty; but , granted, i misused the word 'empty' when i mentioned my  _not working_ solution (but stackoverflow asks you to type in what you've tried, when posting a question so i put that in that textfield - although it's a different scenario.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer but I don't understand the questions in your question, sorry.

Comment: Why do you want to set RS to a regexp? That'd just make the script non-portable for no obvious reason.

Comment: The idea of using an regexp for setting RS, would aim at (possibly) simplifying the command, as such : % awk -vRS="\n$1\n" '/arm64/ 1' logfile  (in a working fashion, mine is just an example here, not working) and resemble the case when there is a truely empty line in the logfile (i.e. no Timestamp , in which case % awk -vRS="\n\n" -vORS="\n\n" '/arch/ 1' logfile does work )

Comment: I added a different answer that I think might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed your solution w/ "awk -v RS='\n.{28}\n'" is more suited. The last question from my side at this point is: would it be possible, instead of matching a certain number of chars, to match against fields, such as: RS="\n$1\n"  (a working equivalent form of this). That way, one can adapt your solution more easily to match "n" fields, instead of just 1st one / a fix number of chars.

Comment: I changed `.{28}` to `\\S+` to match 1 field of any length. You can't set `RS` to match `$1` since `$1` is determined by splitting `$0` after `RS` is matched.

Comment: Thanks , sorry for not having enough reputation to upvote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256475/discussion-between-cg792-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 2):

Already posted answers would work in other awk versions as well. But you insist on a custom `RS` based answer then here is a gnu-awk solution:

```bash
awk -v tgt='amd64' -vORS='\n\n' -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]{4}-[0-9T:.-]+Z\n' '$0 ~ "/" tgt' file

2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085552Z #11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5499792Z #11 DONE 0.1s

2023-12-29T16:05:20.5509862Z #12 [linux/amd64 builder 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5512029Z #12 0.138 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6982466Z #12 ...
```

and:

```bash
awk -v tgt='arm64' -vORS='\n\n' -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]{4}-[0-9T:.-]+Z\n' '$0 ~ "/" tgt' file

2023-12-29T16:05:20.3040485Z #10 [linux/arm64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4084773Z #10 DONE 0.8s

2023-12-29T16:05:21.2474882Z #16 [linux/arm64 runner 2/7] RUN addgroup -S -g 1001 nodejs
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3971789Z #16 ...
```

Take note of `-v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]{4}-[0-9T:.-]+Z\n'` that sets input record separator as 4 digits appearing after start of file or at the line start followed by a hyphen and then 1+ of any given characters inside the character class and ending with letter `Z` and then a line break.

This will break input by block of text appearing between empty timestamps and then finally `$0 ~ "/" tgt` prints only those records that match `tgt` command line argument.

---

Based on comment below if `RS` is to be set when a line has just first field:

```bash
awk -v tgt='arm64' -vORS='\n\n' -v RS='(^|\n)\\S+\n' '$0 ~ "/" tgt' file
```

Comment: Thanks!  one question: what if (as said in my question) the first field is not a Timestamp , how to match then against it in a *general* way , e.g. using fields ($1, $2 ...)?

Comment: That is easy. Just use `awk -v tgt='arm64' -vORS='\n\n' -v RS='(^|\n)\\S+\n' '$0 ~ "/" tgt' file`

Comment: This only works if the lines containing only 1 field (_Timestamp_ in my excerpt) _don't_ have an extra _space_ as last char; you might wanna update your answer accordingly, Thanks

Comment: also, as alluded to in my first comment: how to handle the scenario when we want the RS to 'cover' (match) several fields, not just first one ?

Comment: More specifics needed for that, i.e. how many fields should be considered `RS` or else some specific regex pattern of fields

Comment: say, first n (e.g. 3) fields... some solution along the lines of  using _{3}_ as a _repetition count_ of the regex, such as _RS='(^|\n)\\S+\n'{3}_ . also don't forget about my previous comment about the _space_ after Tstamp, T. y. !

Comment: ok requirements through comments don't help much. I suggest edit your question and add this requirement or better yet open a new question with input and expected output.

Comment: This requirement is already present in my initial question ..."_[solution]  _not be too specific, i.e. work for other first (or n-th) field (not necessary for Timestamp-like formatted field)_

Comment: But there is no input/output data for an example of 3 fields. How would a solution be teted?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

- OP has stated the output is hard to read if we remove the timestamp-only line
- OP has asked to keep the timestamp-only line
- based on actual timestamp values (in the sample input) it looks like we need to keep the *trailing* timestamp-only line
- answer has been updated to keep/print the *trailing* timestamp-only line

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v arch="arm64" '                               # assign awk variable "arch" the name of the chip architecture

function print_block() {                            # use a function to determine if "block" should be printed to stdout
    if (block != "" && block ~ arch)                # if awk variable "block" is not empty and also contains "arch" then ...
       print block ORS $0                           # print current contents of "block" plus the current timestamp-only line
    block = ""                                      # re-init "block"
}

NF <  2 { print_block() }                           # if missing the 2nd field then see if we need to print current contents of "block"
NF >= 2 { block = block (block ? ORS : "") $0 }     # if 2nd field exists then append to "block"; if block is not empty we append with ORS else if block is empty we append with ""
END     { print_block() }                           # print last "block"?
' logfile
```

**NOTE:** replace `print block ORS $0` with `print block ORS ""` to print a blank line in place of the timestamp-only line

With `-v arch="arm64"` this generates:

```
2023-12-29T16:05:20.3040485Z #10 [linux/arm64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4084773Z #10 DONE 0.8s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085104Z
2023-12-29T16:05:21.2474882Z #16 [linux/arm64 runner 2/7] RUN addgroup -S -g 1001 nodejs
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3971789Z #16 ...
2023-12-29T16:05:21.3972318Z
```

With `-v arch="amd64"` this generates:

```
2023-12-29T16:05:20.4085552Z #11 [linux/amd64 builder 1/8] WORKDIR /app
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5499792Z #11 DONE 0.1s
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5505699Z
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5509862Z #12 [linux/amd64 builder 2/8] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
2023-12-29T16:05:20.5512029Z #12 0.138 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6982466Z #12 ...
2023-12-29T16:05:20.6983744Z
```

---

As for OP's requirement - `work for other first (or n-th) field` - something like this may work:

```
awk -v arch="arm64" -v nth_fld=2 '
function ...
NF <  nth_fld { print_block() }
NF >= nth_fld { block = .... }
END ...
' logfile
```

Comment: Thank you for you well-explained answer; could you please consider my LE in my question about preserving the Timestamp-only line?  Also, if you can think of a more contracted answer , i.e. one which is more 'portable' from server-to-server without the overhead of scp-ing the script beforehand, please feel free to post it !

Comment: There isn't , by any chance, any possibility of setting RS via a regexp to an expression resembling RS="\n$1\n" (this one is ofc incorrect)  to match 'newline + $1 of following line + newline' as RS? This would then be used as  % awk -vRS="\n$1\n" '/arch/ 1'  logfile? Thanks

Comment: while modifying the code to preserve the timestamp-only line (or adding a blank line) is relatively simple, the additional requirement for a 'portable' and non-scp answer solution adds a new level of complication to the original question which, in effect, negates the answers you've already received; this would be described as a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478) and is frowned upon; consider up-/down-voting/accepting current answers; if you have problems working these answers into your portable/non-scp solution then ask a new question

Comment: while I can't rule out a possible `RS=<some_regex>` solution I also can say that I'm drawing a blank on what such a solution would look like ... especially in light of your other requirement - `be relatively easy to remember / and intuitively to replicate`; as for the added non-scp solution ... I suggest you look into how to pass an inline script/function for remote execution as part of the `ssh` command line

Comment: Thanks for providing a heads-up regarding 'chameleon questions' , however, please don't be offended (and again Thanks for providing such a good answer) but i had stated in my original question as the first requirement for the solution :  ...not be script-like + "be relatively easy to remember / and intuitively to replicate for repeated similar use-cases"

Comment: all answers (so far) are called `awk programs` or `awk *scripts*`; same for a `perl (script)` or `ruby (script)` solution; I'm guessing many who might answer this question would consider `script` to mean a shell (eg, bash, csh, ksh) script, and in turn would not consider a single `awk / perl / ruby` program as a 'script'; if you're referring to this `awk` (script) as residing on multilpe lines ... that's for readability ... it can easily be collapsed into a not-as-easy-to-read one-liner (eg, for a `ssh` command line)

Comment: you're going to have a hard time finding an answer that is *a)* not script-like *and* *b)* easy to remember *and* *c)* intuitive to replicate *and* *d)* not have to be `scp'd` before running on a remote host; the only 'solution' I can think of that might come close to your requirement would be a (bash) wrapper function that's designed with multiple command-line args; the function would encompass a script-like chunk of code that does all you want so you only call the function on the command line; there are plenty of Q&As on how to pass a function via `ssh` for remote execution

Answer (score 1):

> To which value to set RS in awk to split records based on each line
> whose n-th field is empty?

If you are okay with assuming white-space-sheared file, you might use following `RS` to use 1-column wide lines as separators `"\n[^[:space:]]+\n"`, consider simplified example, let `file.txt` content be

```
1900 zero
1901 one
1903
1905 five
1907 seven
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n[^[:space:]]+\n"}/zero/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1900 zero
1901 one
```

If you want to preserve that line, you might exploit `RT` built-in variable as follows

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n[^[:space:]]+\n"}/zero/{printf("%s%s",$0,RT)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1900 zero
1901 one
1903
```

Explanation: Regular expression is newline (`\n`) followed by one-or-more (`+`) non (`^`) white-space (`[:space:]`) characters followed by newline (`\n`). `RT` hold row terminator of current line, this is useful if you have `RS` which might match different strings. [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) provides

> more precise control over the output format than what is provided by
> `print`

in this case I use it as I do not want trailing newline appended by `print`, `%s` is [Control Letter](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html) which instruct GNU `AWK` to treat what it will get as string, observe that number of control letters must be exactly equal to number of variables rammed, in this case 2.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer; can you explain a little bitte the last awk command , the %s%s and  '^' ?

Comment: @cg792 I have upgraded my answer

Comment: The answer you provided, while working for your _file.txt_ example, doesn't seem to work for my _logfile_  ,i.e. it shows *both* arm64 and amd64 results - can you please check on your part as well ? 

my awk is 
_awk --version
GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2, PMA Avon 8-g1, (GNU MPFR 4.2.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)_

Comment: @cg792 do you have timestamp spanning *whole* lines xor timestamp followed by space character?

Comment: doing _cat -A logfile_ shows (an excerpt):
_2023-12-29T16:10:51.5589804Z #29 [linux/amd64 runner 6/7] COPY --from=builder /app/locales ./locales$
2023-12-29T16:10:51.5590629Z #29 DONE 0.1s$
2023-12-29T16:10:51.7092737Z $
2023-12-29T16:10:51.7094548Z #30 [linux/amd64 runner 7/7] COPY --from=builder /app/config/marketing/config.json ./config/marketing/$
2023-12-29T16:10:51.7095697Z #30 DONE 0.0s$
2023-12-29T16:10:51.7096183Z $_
 There is a space before the last "$"
LE: can't get italics to show  or any other formatting :(